# Using getopt with no arguments

Tags: c, input

**By default I want the program will read input from stdin and send it's output to stdout.**
The -f option will cause the
program to read the input from a text file and the -o option will cause the program to write the
output to a file instead of stdout.
The –c if specified will display the output in a CSV format (either in stdout or to a file depending if -o is specified).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    char opt;
    char *filename_in, *filename_out;
    int i, flagC=0,flagF=0,flagO=0;

    while((opt = getopt(argc,argv,"cf:o:")) != -1){
        switch(opt){
        case 'c':
            flagC=1;
            break;
        case 'o':
            flagO=1;
            filename_out = optarg;
            break;
        case 'f':
            flagF=1;
            filename_in = optarg;
            openFile(filename_in);
            break;
        case '?':
            printf("Opt ?");
            return 0;
        default:
            printf("Opt Default");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    if((flagC==0) && (flagO==0) && (flagF==0)){
        //  puts("Please enter a string:");
    }

    for (i = optind; i < argc; i++)
        printf("%s ", argv[i]); //prints anything without argument and space between
    return 0;
}
```

**Is there a better way to read input from stdin aside from checking each flag I created is set to 0?**

```
char input[100];

if((flagC==0) && (flagO==0) && (flagF==0)){
            //  puts("Please enter a string:");
            //  scanf("%s", &input);
        }
```

Comment: `if((flagC==0) & (flagO==0) & (flagF==0))` should be `if((flagC==0) && (flagO==0) && (flagF==0))`. `&` does bit wise *or* the operators's two arguments. That is not what you want. `&&` is the logical *or* operator.

Comment: @alk You are correct. A typo on my part sorry! Any suggestion though for a better way of handling this aside from my method here? I am going to go through the *NIX source code for the command ls and others to learn more.